# data structure list class in python

Tags: python, list

I am working on a data structure list class in python. I would like to get the largest item in the list.

```
    inlist = self.data
    if inlist[0] > inlist[1]:
        largest = inlist[0]
    else:
        largest = inlist[1]

    for item in inlist[2]:
        if item > largest:
            largest = item
    return largest
```

With the above getting stuck at largest gets returns

```
<bound method ListData.largest2 of <list.ListData instance at 0x2b35602c3440>>
```

while the data

```
[2, 5]
```

Comment: um, yeah, your list is only 2 items long, there is no `inlist[2]`

Comment: i guess you're trying to avoid using already built in functions? `max(self.data)` ?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the output you're getting? You normally see things like `<blah hex-code for memory address>` when you forget something silly, like forgetting the trailing parenthesis in a function that takes zero arguments.

Comment: You need to explain what your structure looks like. You're trying to iterate over the third item in `self.data`, so clearly you're expecting that to be a `list` or other iterable. So… what is it a list or iterable of? For example, is your structure in `self.data` something like `(len, capacity, [item0, item1, ...])`? Ideally, give us the actual class definition (stripped down to just enough to run a test that shows the problem), either posted here or somewhere like pastebin.com.

Comment: when i print out listdata.data it returns : [2, 5]

Comment: Is it not the case that you're doing something like. ``print data.largest2`` instead of ``print data.largest2()`` - as it looks like you're printing the method not the result of calling the method. It would help if you revealed more of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the build in [max()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function.

```
mylist = [2, 5]
mymax = max(mylist)
```

Comment: <bound method ListData.largest5 of <list.ListData instance at 0x2adc79695ef0>>

Answer (score 1):

Trust the loop to get all the indicies rather than specifying them yourself.

```
if len(self.data) == 0:
  return None
result = self.data[0]
for item in self.data:
  if item > result:
    result = item
return result
```

that for loop is going through all your data.  Trying to coerce an index got you into trouble.

Comment: it still returns 
<bound method ListData.largest3 of <list.ListData instance at 0x2adc79695ef0>>
<bound method ListData.largest4 of <list.ListData instance at 0x2adc79695ef0>>

Comment: Sounds like self.data isn't an array of numerics.  What did you put in self.data?

Comment: def data(self):
        return self.data

Comment: doh!  Change the word "largest" to "temp" wherever it occurs.  I bet you defined and used largest as something else in a different part of your code.

Comment: I suspect you have (another) problem in the code not included here. Likely culprits include bad indentation on your `def myFunction:` line